# *ngFor value child array

Tags: angular, ngfor

How can I repeat only the values of the `recommendaciones` object with `*ngFor`?. For example, I am now repeating the values in this way:

```
<div ngFor="let producto of productos">
  <div> {{ producto.titulo }} </div>
    <div>Recomendaciones: 
      <span *ngFor="let producto of productos.recomendaciones">
        {{ producto.recomendaciones }}</span>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

But how do I get to repeat each value of `recommendaciones` in an individual `span`?

service.ts

```
getProductos() {

  this.productos = [
    {
      id: 'lomoFino',
      titulo: 'Lomo fino',
      descripcion: 'Es la pieza más fina de la res, de textura tierna.',
      recomendaciones: ['Guisos', 'Freir', 'Plancha'],
      ubicacion: 'Lomo',
    },
    {
      id: 'colitaCuadril',
      titulo: 'Colita de cuadril',
      descripcion: 'Es un corte triangular y ligeramente marmoleado.',
      recomendaciones: ['Guisos', 'Freir', 'Horno'],
      ubicacion: 'Trasera',
   },
   {
     id: 'asadoCuadrado',
     titulo: 'Asado cuadrado',
     descripcion: 'Corte fibroso, de sabor agradable.',
     recomendaciones: ['Guisos', 'Freir', 'Plancha'],
     ubicacion: 'Entrepierna',
   }
]

return this.productos
}
```

Comment: `<span *ngFor="let rec of producto.recomendaciones">{{ rec }}</span>`

Comment: I think you were on the right track, but made a typo: instead of `productos.recomendaciones` you should use `producto.recomendaciones`. The one ending with s points to _all_ of them, while the singular one is the one that's expanded already in the ngFor - and also the nested *ngFor should have a different variable name, so you don't try to redeclare it

Comment: @AlexSzabó Yes, you're right. I just paste the code above and changed it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a new variable `recomendacion` taken from `producto.recomendaciones` and print `{{ recomendacion }}` for every `span`.

Also fix the outer `*ngFor` (See [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)), the `*` is missing. Like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let producto of productos">
  <div> {{ producto.titulo }} </div>
  <div>Recomendaciones:
    <span *ngFor="let recomendacion of producto.recomendaciones">
            {{ recomendacion }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- there was an additional </div> here (maybe a typo?), make sure to remove it -->
```

See **[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcnbdw?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation this worked perfectly. I understand the approach, take the values of something that has already been printed and iterate it with a new variable.

Answer (score 2):

you need to iterate through the recomendations of the product and print out each one of them.

```
<div ngFor="let producto of productos">
    <div> {{ producto.titulo }} </div>
        <div>Recomendaciones: 
            <span *ngFor="let recomendacion of producto.recomendaciones">
                {{ recomendacion  }}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not much clear about the question. But check the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let producto of productos"> <!--iterate each product-->
  <div> {{ producto.titulo }} </div>
    <div>Recomendaciones: 
      <span *ngFor="let recomendacion of producto.recomendaciones"> 
<!--Iterate recomendacion of the product-->
        {{ recomendacion }}</span>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Actually this is like a **for loop** inside a **for loop** (nested)